# Slick slider - Infinity loop current slide selected clone element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I used slick slider on my React project, i have breakpoints, if on 480 screens infinity loop is true selected clone element, i want my first element in slider started not clone. Who i can it ?

[image]

```
var settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    initialSlide: 0,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    arrows: products.length > 4 ? true : false,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 4,
                infinite: true,
                dots: false,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                infinite: true,
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 2
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                infinite: true,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `breakpoint event` and then check if the window `width` is less or equal than `480px`. Then, you set the `slide` you need.

(Call it at least once to check if it's starting at a >`480px` device).

I assume you are using `jQuery` because of Slick Slider.

```
$my-slider.on('breakpoint', function(eventick, breakpoint) { // if breakpoint change
  setSlide();
});

function setSlide() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
    $('.my-slider').slick('slickGoTo', 1); // the number of slide you need
  }
}
setSlide(); // call it once at least
```

Hope it help you somehow.